# WiFiClient.cpp socket error "Software caused connection abort - PlatformIo

Tags: c++, http, arduino

For a project I am working on a mesh network on ESP32 (devkit).
I'm using the https://gitlab.com/painlessMesh/painlessMesh library for this to work.

The data received by the other ESP32's need to be sended to an REST API on Home Assistent with adres: http://192.168.1.4:8123/api/states/sensor.mesh.

To to this I am using the https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/http/ library to send these HTTP requests.

This is my code:

```
#include <painlessMesh.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define   MESH_PREFIX     "MeshNetwork"
#define   MESH_PASSWORD   "MeshPassword"
#define   MESH_PORT       5555

const char* ssid_wifi = "<wifissid>";
const char* password_wifi  = "<wifipassword>";

painlessMesh  mesh;
Scheduler userScheduler;

void receivedCallback( uint32_t from, String &msg ) {
  Serial.printf("Received from %u msg=%s\n", from, msg.c_str());
  
// Send To Home Assistent 
  Serial.printf("Node %u sends to HA....\n", from);
  WiFiClient client;
  HTTPClient http;
  String serverName = "http://192.168.1.4:8123/api/states/sensor.mesh";
  http.begin(client, serverName);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <TOKEN>");
  String httpRequestData = "{\"state\":"+ String(random(0,30));
  Serial.println(httpRequestData + ", \"attributes\": {\"unit_of_measurement\": \"°C\"}}");
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData + ", \"attributes\": {\"unit_of_measurement\": \"°C\"}}");
  Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  http.end();
}

void newConnectionCallback(uint32_t nodeId) {
    Serial.printf("startHere: New Connection found!, nodeId = %u\n", nodeId);
}
void changedConnectionCallback() {
  Serial.printf("Changed connections\n");
}
void nodeTimeAdjustedCallback(int32_t offset) {
    Serial.printf("Adjusted time %u. Offset = %d\n", mesh.getNodeTime(),offset);
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid_wifi, password_wifi);
  Serial.printf("\n Connecting to Wifi: %s", ssid_wifi);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("\n Connected to Wifi! \n ");


  // start Mesh Network
  mesh.setDebugMsgTypes(ERROR | MESH_STATUS | CONNECTION | SYNC | COMMUNICATION | GENERAL | MSG_TYPES | REMOTE  ); 
  mesh.init( MESH_PREFIX, MESH_PASSWORD, &userScheduler, MESH_PORT);
  
  // Set Root Node
  mesh.setContainsRoot(true);

  // Mesh Events
  mesh.onReceive(&receivedCallback);
  mesh.onNewConnection(&newConnectionCallback);
  mesh.onChangedConnections(&changedConnectionCallback);
  mesh.onNodeTimeAdjusted(&nodeTimeAdjustedCallback);
}

void loop() {
  mesh.update();
}
```

When the data is sending it gives me the following error

**[E][WiFiClient.cpp:258] connect(): socket error on fd 61, errno: 113, "Software caused connection abort"
HTTP Response code: -1**

I don't know what to do know,I have tried a lot of things.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Update: When requesting the HTTP POST in the setup() it works. Not in the loop()

Comment: A connection abort can indicate the server crashed or maybe a firewall issue

Comment: @AlanBirtles Home Assistent (the server) is running smoothly. I'll look into the firewall.